# How to optimize and DRY scopes in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

In order do DRY my application, I defined the 'visible' scope (which exists for all my tables) in the application_record.rb file:

```
scope :visible, -> { where "is_active" }
```

and when I query the list of objects, if I need to scope the data, I write the following int the controller:

```
def index
@values_lists = ValuesList.joins(requested_values_lists).visible.search(params[:criteria]).
  select(index_fields).order(order_by).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => paginate_lines)
```

Actually, this values_lists table is linked to the users table (defining the owner), and the business_areas table (defining the parent). To optimize the query, I try to retrieve values_list, parent and owner in the same query, with Arel:

```
def values_lists
  ValuesList.arel_table
end

def values_lists_parent
  BusinessArea.arel_table.alias('parent')
end

def values_lists_owner
  User.arel_table.alias('owner')
end

def requested_values_lists
  values_lists.
  join(values_lists_parent).on(values_lists[:business_area_id].eq(values_lists_parent[:id])).
  join(values_lists_owner).on(values_lists[:owner_id].eq(values_lists_owner[:id])).
  join_sources
end

def index_fields
  [values_lists[:id], values_lists[:code], values_lists[:name], values_lists[:description], values_lists[:status_id], values_lists[:updated_by], values_lists[:updated_at], values_lists_parent[:code], values_lists_owner[:name]]
end
```

The query works fine without the scope, but when applying the scope, I get the message stating "ambigous column name is_active". Is there a way to work around this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does `{ where "#{self.table_name}.is_active" }` work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by letting Rails do the smart work:

in **application_record.rb**

```
scope :visible, -> { where is_active: true }
```

resolves the table name by itself!